# Serial Data communication Arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino, deserialization

I currently am trying to read the serial output from a small capacitance meter(model DN060-02v04 from JYETECH). I have the arduino UNO set up to read the meter output. I do get data, but it is not readable and does not correspond to the format outlined in the manual. My baud rates match at 38400bps. The meter claims a 8-N-1 configuration. I'm using the SerialSoftware example in the Arduino Library to read it.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("Begin");
  mySerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
 if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
 if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

This is what i get:

```
3M$¦Ò)ºÁÁ¹aà3PL¦©ÊÁÁ¹eà3PL&rÂÉÁa\`à
3&ÓrÒÍÁa\`à
3PL&râÕÁa\bà
3M$¦+rÊÙÁa\dà3PL&+rÚáÁa\`à
3JiÂ¹ÁåA``\1¸3PL&SÉQÁÁ¹aà3N$¦SÉÁÁ¹eà3PL&S)Éi¢ÁÁ¹eà3L$¦S+Éu²ÁÁ¹aà
3PL&SKÉÚÁÁyaà
3&ÓSSÉIÊÁÁ¹aà3PL&+iÉ    ÁÁ¹eà
3M$¦SkÉAÒÁÁ¹eà
3PL&iÉÚÁÁ¹eà
3JiÒ¹ÉÕA``\0¸3PL&SÉaºÁÁ¹aà3N$¦S«É   ÂÁÁ¹eà3PL&S«ÉQÂÁÁ9eà
3L$¦S«ÉÁÁ¹aà3PL&3ÉÉ)ÚÁÁ¹aà
3&ÓSÓÉi¢ÁÁ¹aà3PL&SëÉ²ÁÁ¹eà3M$¦SëÉQºÁÁ¹ià3PL&SëÉÊÁÁ¹eà3Ii
¢Æá¹Ñe@``®¸Ã3PL&SrâÉÁa\`à
3N$¦S+rÊÑÁa\bà3PL&#)rÚÕÁa\bà
3L$¦ÉÚÁÁ9aà
3PL&ÉÂÁÁ¹aà3ÓS  É©ÁÁ¹aà3PL&+É1ÁÁ¹eà3M$¦
+ÉqÁÁ¹ià3PL&KÉ)ªÁÁ¹aà3JiÊ¹ÕÙA``\0¸3PL&IÉ©ÂÁÁ¹aà
3N$¦kÉ1ÊÁÁ¹eà
3PL&SiÉÁÁ¹ià3L$¦ÉIÒÁÁ¹aà
3PL&KÉÉâÁÁ¹aà
3&Ó³É   ²ÁÁ¹aà3PL&«ÉEºÁÁ¹eà3M$¦«É
ÊÁÁ¹ià3PL&ËÉ1ÁÁ¹aà3JiÚ¹ÝÉA``\1¸3PL&SéÉ)ÁÁ¹aà3N$¦ëÉ©ÊÁÁ9aà
```

Comment: Ask here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/does-an-arduino-serial-port-expect-8-n-1-or-7-e-1

Comment: and what does the output look like? (providing full info makes it easier for someone to help).

Comment: That looks like either noise or baud rate mismatch.  Are you sure your serial monitor on the computer is set to the right baud rate?  Are you sure your TX and RX lines are hooked up correctly (have you tried swapping them)?  Have you tried other rates in case the manual is wrong?

Comment: Baud rates are all set to 38400. Tried changing them, still get garbage. Arduino RX to module TX, module ground to Arduino ground.